# VirtualBox inaccessible

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

The following issue is stopping me from working in VirtualBox. I cannot start it, as you can see per image. 
The file VBoxGuestAdditions.iso is in the correct folder and does exist/is accessible. I did nothing but shutdown the computer. Does anyone know why this is?

[image]

Comment: do you have another VM running with this ISO mounted

Comment: I fixed the problem by ejecting the .iso file in the manager! Seems to be a bug or somesort!